# error jsp 154 java.lang.classnotfound

Tags: jboss, struts2, ejb, liferay

i am developing a portlet struts 2 ejb3
i configured project ejb and in the portlet project i confugured the action class and struts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
 <package namespace="/view" extends="struts-portlet-default" name="view">
     <!-- If no class attribute is specified the framework will assume success and
        render the result index.jsp -->
        <!-- If no name value for the result node is specified the success value is the default -->
  <action name="index">
   <result>/html/view/index.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="create" method="ajouterOUmodifier" class="com.esprit.action.AdressAction">
          <result name="success" type="redirect">index</result>
           <result name="input">/html/view/ajoutAdress.jsp</result>
    </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

and the jsp file

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="<s:url value="/resources/main.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="create" method="post">

 <s:textfield name="adress.nom" label="Firstname"/>
  <s:textfield name="adress.prenom" label="Lastname"/>
                <s:submit value="ok" />
        </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i execute the project an error is display:

> ERROR [jsp:154] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esprit.metier.AdressDao from BaseClassLoader@33b2c7a8{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1e52011c{name=vfsfile:/D:/android/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/DepartmentWEB-portlet.war/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@69ac5f83{name=vfsfile:/D:/android/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/DepartmentWEB-portlet.war/ parentPolicy=AFTER_BUT_JAVA_BEFORE parent=ClassLoaderDomain@5183a17c{DefaultDomain}} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@432465105[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o13m-e9nqdk-h49ogxti-1-h49ohbp5-2a

can you help me ?

Comment: Is your code really indented at random like that? In any case, I'm not sure how we can help at this point--where does that class live?

Answer (score 0):

The ClassNotFound condition can result from two issues:

1. The class that the classloader complains about is not on the classpath
2. The class that the classloader complains about references another class that cannot be loaded for some reason (e.g. it's not on the classpath or references something else that is not...)

So: Check your classpath: Is `com.esprit.metier.AdressDao` on there? Its superclasses (the whole hierarchy) and all interfaces it implements? All members and referenced classes (see method signatures as well).

Further, if this really is a portlet's jsp, it shouldn't contain `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` as this is the business of the portal to add these to the page. You'll also probably need to include your css either in the theme or in liferay-portlet.xml in the `<header-css>` section (but this shouldn't influence your class-not-found experiences, it's just general portal advice)